# Possible missunderstanding of how pass by value works

Tags: java, reference, pass-by-value

I'm not sure if I understand how pass-by-value works in Java. I know there are many topics about that, even on SO, but they all don't really fit and I'd like to know if I'm right:

Lets say I've got the following Code:

```
class Class{
    public String className;
    public Person p;
}

class Person {
    public String name;
}
```

The thing I don't 100% understand is:

```
Class c = new Class(); // reference of the object oC is stored in var c
Person p = new Person();// reference of the object oP is stored in var p
p.name = "StudName"; // value = reference of string s is stored in var p
c.p = p; // reference of p is updated to point to oP
p = new Person(); // Confusing Part (1)
```

So as far as I understand, each Variable has a given space in the Stack and points to the reference of the object right? So am I correct, that the `p = new Person();` doesn't affect the reference in the `c` Object, because this operation sets the reference of `p` to the one from the newly created Person object?

I find that hard to understand, because if I do something like that:

```
c.p = new Person();//(2)
```

This will affect the reference of `c.p` of course. But what's the difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: probably duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: @JacekCz No it's not really a duplicate, because there is not explained how the re-assigining works like here

Comment: Actually "value = reference of string s is stored in var p" is wrong. It is not stored in p, but in the field "name". In (1) you say that the variable p will be a reference to a new Person. In (2) you say that the reference p stored as a variable in c will point to a new Person. In (2), c will still point to the original Class instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with pass-by-value*. Your question is about object references.

> each Variable has a given space in the Stack and points to the reference of the object right?

You have one too many levels of indirection in there. :-) The variable contains the object reference.

Think of an object reference as an `int` that tells the JVM where the object is elsewhere in memory. (That's not literally true, but it's a very good way of thinking about it.)

So in:

```
c.p = p;
```

the value in `p` (an object reference saying where that `Person` object is) is copied into `c.p`, modifying the state of the object `c`. There is **no** ongoing relationship between `p` and `c.p`, they just happen to contain the same value for the moment.

This is exactly like if we had an `int i` in the class and did:

```
int i = 42;
c.i = i;
```

The *value* in `i` is copied into `c.i`, modifying the state of `c`.

After the `c.p = ...` line, when you do this:

```
p = new Person(); // Confusing Part (1)
```

...it has no effect on `c.p` **at all**. It just creates a new `Person` object and stores the object reference in `p`. `c.p` still has the old value (the reference to the earlier object).

> But what's the difference between (1) and (2)?

In (1), you're assigning to `p`, not `c.p`; doing so has no effect on `c.p`. In (2) you're assigning to `c.p`.

Let's follow that first code block through, but I'm going to use `Container` rather than `Class` as Java already has a `Class` class. After you do this:

```
Container c = new Container();
Person p = new Person();
p.name = "StudName";
```

you have something like this in memory:

```
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
c: [Ref11325]−−−>|   (Container)   |
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                 | className: null |
                 | p: null         |
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
p: [Ref21354]−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>|    (Person)      |
                                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                         | name: [Ref54312] |−−−>|  (String)  |
                                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                                 | "studName" |
                                                                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

*(Leaving out many details; the string, for instance, actually refers to a `char[]` array elsewhere and has several other fields.)*

The `Ref11325` in `c`, `Ref21354` in `p`, and `Ref54312` in `p`'s `name` field are just there to show that they contain references; we never see a reference's actual value.

Then when you do:

```
c.p = p;
```

you have (only change is `c`'s `p`, of course):

```
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
c: [Ref11325]−−−>|   (Container)   |
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                 | className: null |
                 | p: [Ref21354]   |−−+
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                                      |
                                      \    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
p: [Ref21354]−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−>|    (Person)      |
                                           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                           | name: [Ref54312] |−−−>|  (String)  |
                                           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                                   | "studName" |
                                                                   +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

See how `Ref21354` was copied from `p` to `c.p`.

Then finally, when you do:

```
p = new Person();
```

you have this:

```
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
c: [Ref11325]−−−>|   (Container)   |
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                 | className: null |       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                       
                 | p: [Ref21354]   |−−−−−−>|    (Person)      |                       
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                           | name: [Ref54312] |−−−>|  (String)  |
                                           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                                   | "studName" |
                                                                   +−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                                           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
p: [Ref34851]−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>|    (Person)     |
                                           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                           | name: null      |
                                           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

`p` now contains a new reference, but that has no effect at all on `c.p`.

---

* "Pass-by-value" and "pass-by-reference" are terms of art and relate to what happens when you pass a variable into a function:

```
doSomething(someVariable);
```

In pass-by-value, the *value* of `someVariable` is passed into `doSomething`. In pass-by-reference, a *reference* to the `someVariable` variable is passed into `doSomething`. In pass-by-reference, the function can reach out and change the contents of the variable. In pass-by-value, it cannot.

The word "reference" in "pass-by-reference" has nothing to do with the word "reference" in object references, it's just two things defined using the same overloaded word. The "reference" in pass-by-reference is a reference to a *variable*, not an object.

Comment: Awesome answer. Many thanks for your detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

During my preparation to the OCA and OCP certification I found a very good advice - to paint each relation on the paper.

In your case relations between objects, values and references will be following.
[image]

In operation #5 you will remove connection which was created during operation #2 (see dotted line).

Illustrations should help more than any explanation in words. Hope this will help.

Comment: Much prettier than my ASCII-art. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks. Sorry, I missed your post for some reason... maybe because was involved in painting. =)

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
Person p = new Person();
```

An instance of `Person` is created on the heap (first instance), and exists as long as something references it.  `p` is a variable on the stack, and its value is a reference to that instance.

When you do this:

```
p = new Person();
```

An instance of `Person` is again created on the heap (second instance).  The local variable `p` is assigned the new value of a reference to that instance.  The previous instance (first instance) no longer has any reference to it, and is garbage collected.

When you do this:

```
c.p = new Person();
```

An instance of `Person` is again created on the heap (third instance).  The local variable `p` was unaffected of course, so the "second instance" is unaffected as well.  The local variable `c` also still points to an instance of `Class` on the heap, which is still its first instance.  That instance includes a class-level variable called `p`, which now follows the same rules as the second example above.  It previously pointed to an instance of `Person` on the heap, and its value is updated to point to a new instance (third instance).

The "value" in these variables is simply a kind of address in the heap where the object exists.